# Why does this expression need to be instantiated - or does it?

Tags: swift

I'm working through a Core Data exercise which uses a lazy var in which an NSPredicate is "lazily-instantiated" as follows:

```
lazy var moderateVenuePredicate: NSPredicate = {
return NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(Venue.priceInfo.priceCategory), "$$")}()
```

Note the parenthesis at the end which force the instantiation (or "evaluation") of the variable.

Now after typing this it wasn't clear to me why this needed to be "lazily instantiated". Why, I wondered, wouldn't the program run if I simply wrote instead the following line which is basically the same but without the forced instantiation?:

```
lazy var moderateVenuePredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(Venue.priceInfo.priceCategory), "$$")
```

I was expecting the program to crash and reveal to me what I did wrong, but to my surprise the program worked even with this change (!?). So my question now is what is going on here? Was the textbook's recommended lazy instantiation of this variable really needed? What is the need for the lazy instantiation if the program works just fine without it?

Comment: Both are lazy properties but in the first one you are using a closure to initialise the property.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - Yes, I understand that but operationally what is the difference? As I wrote, both ways seem to work equally well in the Core Data exercise code that I have.

Comment: First of all , this isn’t specific to Core Data and secondly , there is no difference. The reason to use a closure is if your code contains several lines/commands which isn’t the case here.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: "...and secondly , there is no difference. The reason to use a closure is if your code contains several lines/commands which isn’t the case here" - OK, thanks.